# Callback for every loaded dependency in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'd like to get a function called when javascript library is loaded by RequireJS. I'd use this to indicate initial initialisation to the user. It **normally** takes less than a second, but if it takes longer, user ends up staring on blank screen and thinking the web application is out of order. I imagine such screen:

[image: image description]

I can catch **fails**:

```
requirejs.onError = function(error) {
  error.requireModules.forEach(function(name) {
    //Create basename in case this was an URL
    name.replace(/^.*[/]/, "");
    // Debug
    console.warn("Module failed to load: ", name);
    // Find the loading node (they are hardcoded) and 
    // if it exists mark it as failed
    var element = document.getElementById("loading_"+name);
    if(element) {
      element.className+=" failed";
    }
  });
}
```

So I can prepare popup like on that image and report failures in it. But reporting success is also important. Now there's one option **I don't want to use**:

```
var require = {
    deps: ["some/module1", "my/module2", "a.js", "b.js"],
    callback: function(module1, module2) {
        //This function will be called when all the dependencies
        //listed above in deps are loaded. Note that this
        //function could be called before the page is loaded.
        //This callback is optional.
    }
};
```

Because:

- It only executes if **all** dependencies are loaded, rather than on every single one
- It would form another location I have to update if my dependencies change (and I'd have to keep it in sync with my loading popup)

What I want is the **opposite of `onError`**. Call callback every time modules are successfully loaded. It would be useful for debug purposes too.